# As if I am/I were/I was

Tags: usage, conditional-constructions

When forming a conditional clause with "if", when should I choose "if I am", instead of "if I were" or  "if I was"?

I think *was* is never correct, but may be acceptable for informal use.

I'm writing a song lyric:

> If, after life, I satisfy myself for feeling more alive,
>
> will I still feel alive **as if I'm** breathing?"

Am I correct for choosing "as if I am"? Would "as if I were breathing" be better?

Comment: I don't think your proposed "lyric" makes sense, and I don't see how tinkering with the syntax could improve this. What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: "If I go to a better state, will I miss how this feels?" But I'd like to use "as if I," but can't decide what goes after that--"am," "was," or "were"? In my example I go for "am."

Answer (score 1):

> I **am**
>   I **am** ten pounds heavier now.

you are something **now**

> I **were**
>   [If I **Were** A Rich Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBHZFYpQ6nc)

if you were *hypothetically* something

> I **was**
>   I **was** 10 pounds lighter in my twenties.

you were something in the **past**

For your lyrics

> as if I **was** breathing
>   as if I **were** breathing

could both be used depending on what you are trying to say.

Comment: It can't be "am"? Also, is that correct, I am I am?

Comment: "I am I am" was a formatting error.

Comment: So, what's it supposed to be? Also, what about for the future? It has "will," right?

Answer (score 1):

"**as if I am**" doesn't make sense. You either *are* or *pretend to be*.

The correct way to construct a hypothetical phrase is to use "**as if I were**"

Another possible way is "**like if I were**". I also rarely came across "**as though I were**".